# Stumped on ServiceModel.FaultException forever

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, wcf

So I'm still not sure if this is on my side, the service side, or both sides. I have NO idea where the main source of the issue is coming from, but I will try and do my best to explain the steps I have taken and what has happened so far so you guys have all the info you need to bang your head against this with me.

So we have a Web Service class called API.svc that implements one of our classes containing one method. In the API class is where the call goes out to the service, however it seems to be failing before that so I think that the problem is coming locally. Note I said I THINK.

The first time we ran into an error was running the code normally, and testing this after not testing it in a while. The error that came back when we clicked the button that ran through all the calls (eventually needing to hit the service call), was this:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Akcelerant.Core.Data.DAL.SQL.OpenConnection()
   at Akcelerant.Core.Data.DAL.SQL.BuildCommand(String SQL)
   at Akcelerant.Core.Data.DAL.SQL.Execute(String SQL, Int32& Retur...).
```

Now, when debugging, Visual Studio wouldn't let me debug INTO the web service class (API.svc) that implements our class. It came up with a dialogue that said like, "Remote debugging is not available on the specified instance" -- or something like that. It asked me if I wanted to enable it, so I clicked Yes, but I don't think it really worked. Now when I try stepping into it I'm getting an exception back that reads this:

```
"Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'qa2automated' failed. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance."
```

However it won't let me read the exception (I'm assuming its the same one I get when not debugging though). The error message I just described is a dialogue box that pops up in Visual Studio. 'qa2automated' is a server on our network however NOT the server I am working on. Could that have something to do with it? And why would it be trying to connect to a non-local server when I am developing completely local right now. However, when this code DOES run on the 'qa2automated' server, it recieves the SAME error. I'm so confused.

What could this be? I've seriously been stumped on this for so long. Does anyone know what the solution could be for this, or what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the service endpoint URL was pointing to qa2automated...even though the web.config was right, it would never get to the correct DB because it would try those CnnStr's on the qa2 DB.